# Generate dates based on external shift id in postgres function

Tags: postgresql

I have shifts per employee on  a specific day.

I want to create days based on shift count per day.
used generate_series in Postgres. It works fine for current_date.
I want to do it for past days, based on count of shift per that day.

```
date         shift
2020-07-30   5317
             5318
```

expected output

```
date         shift
2020-07-30   5317
2020-07-30   5318
```

Doing it for roster based attendance

Comment: I don't understand the first sample data. Is that the contents of your table? If yes, why do you have a `null` value in the `date` colum? And how would you know to fill it with the "previous" value? Why not the day after?

Comment: Where do the magic numbers (5317, 5318) come from? How do they relate to the date?